# The least value of a constant for which the inverse of a function is defined

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $f(x) = x^2 +6x -4$ has an inverse for all $ x>a$ , then
Find

1. The least value of $a$
2. If a= 0 , then find the domain of $f^{-1}$

My turn:

> 1. We note that
>      $$ f(x) = (x+3)^2 -13. $$ 
>      Thus the curve is symmetric about the line $x=-3$ then the inverse is defined if $x\geq -3 $ or $x\leq -3$
>      Then the least value if $a$ is $-3$.
> 2. If $a=0$ , then the domain of $f^{-1}$ is $x\geq 0$
>      Is the solution correct ?

Comment: How do you obtain the answer 2. ?

Comment: The function is one-to-one if $x\geq -3$

Answer (score 1):

We note that $$ f(x) = x^2 - 6x - 4 = (x-3)^2 - 13$$
is strictly increasing for $x > 3$ and strictly decreasing for $x < 3$. Thus the least value of $a$ such that $f$ has an inverse for $x > a$ is $a = 3$.

If $a = 0$, then $f$ is not injective and therefore not invertible. However, the range of $f$ is 
$$ [-13, -4) \cup [-13, +\infty) = [-13, +\infty). $$

Comment: There was a miss-typing in the question , i have edited it

Answer (score 1):

Try drawing a graph of $f$, rotate it $90^\circ$ clockwise, then flip it vertically [this works best of you can see through the paper, so don't do this with a piece of plywood; I use MS Paint for these manipulations]. Note, the portion of $f$ where it's domain is greater than zero [e.g. $a$] has a range of $[-4,\infty]$, which, of course, is $f^{-1}$'s domain.

[image]